# Which avr programmers can be used for atmega164PA?

Tags: avr, atmega, programmer

I searched for a programmer for ATMega164PA on ebay and found nothing specific to it. Is there any **standard** programmer to program this chip?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the datasheet, the ATmega164A supports AVR ISP, HVPP, and JTAG. Any programmer that supports any of those will work when combined with the appropriate software.

Comment: Is there any programmer suggested by Atmel for it?

Comment: They want you to buy the AVR ONE!. But I use a $3 EvUSBasp.

Comment: I cant take risk of burning my laptop USB port.

Comment: @barej  No guts - no glory.

Comment: Any other good programmer suggested by you?

Comment: I haven't used any others, but I hear good things about the AVRISP mkII and the AVR Dragon.

Comment: do you have any comment about such [microcontroller development boards](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Mini-System-AVR-ATmega16-microcontroller-development-board-USB-Cable-/400430837322?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_15&hash=item5d3b89ae4a)?

Comment: I wouldn't bother using one for a DIL, but I have nothing against them per se. Note that they usually don't include a programmer though.

Comment: AVR ISP mk2 has always given me troubles, but the USBASP that @NickAlexeev suggests are amazing, and ultra cheap.

Answer (score 0):

"Officially" supported tools are listed on [Atmel's website](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega164pa.aspx?tab=tools), though as Ignacio said most AVR chips support many different publicly available protocols and that there are tons of available third party programmers which work just as well just by having the correct firmware/software. For example, you can [upload a sketch to an Arduino to do ISP](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP).

Comment: Then one suggested on the website is AVRISP mkII which converts USB to JTag but I need something to mount AVR on it without need to another board.

Comment: Use a breadboard. The data-rates are small enough that as long as you have some short-ish cables (say, under a few feet, depends mostly on the programmer) you can program most AVR chips. The AVR Dragon also has a small unpopulated region you can put header pins for this purpose.